# opening only one window on actionPerformed

Tags: java, swing, jframe, actionlistener

I've looked through topics on how to open only one window when a button is clicked but none of the solutions there helped, perhaps because my code was structured a bit differently.

So I have a main window class extending JFrame and one of the buttons is supposed to open a new window when clicked. I have defined the widgets/panels etc for the new window in a separate class. At the moment, every time I click on the button a new window is opened. I want to make it so that if a window is already opened then it would switch to that window once the button is clicked again.

Here is a bit of my code:

```
public class MainWindow extends JFrame{

    /*
     * create widgets and panels
     */
    Button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { // the button that opens 
                                                    //a new window

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    Window2 ww = new Window2(); //creating the new window here

                }
            });
    }
```

**NB. The Window2 class is also extending JFrame, if that's of any help.**

Thanks

Comment: you have to store your Window2 object in your MainWindow class, you create/show/put in foreground when your action is performed

Comment: *"I've looked through topics on how to open only one window.."*  What are the links to those topics?

Comment: *"the Window2 class is also extending JFrame,.."*  Don't extend frame, and never have two of them.  See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)  Note that if the 2nd 'window' is actually a modal `JDialog`, it will not be possible for the user to open it twice at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a full working example:

**Window2.java**

```
public class Window2 extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7843480295403205677L;

}
```

**MainWindow.java**

```
public class MainWindow extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9170930657273608379L;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
        mw.go();
    }

    private void go() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private void createAndShowGUI() {
        JButton button = new JButton("Click me");

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            private Window2 ww = null;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (ww==null) {
                    ww = new Window2(); //creating the new window here
                    ww.setDefaultCloseOperation(HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
                    ww.setTitle("Window2 created on " + new Date());
                    ww.setSize(500, 200);
                }

                pack();
                ww.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(button);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I already tried this with exactly the same if statement but I didn't know what to putin the else sstatement so that it switches to the opened window. It kept opening new windows when I clicked the button though, shouldn't it just do nothing?

Comment: @user3281466 I have updated my answer with a full working example.

Comment: Ah thanks man, I had nearly the same code but it seems that it didn't work because I had defined setVisible(true) in the Window2 class and I didn't explicitly invoke it on the ww object in the actionPerformed method. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

pull out ojbect creation from `actionPerformed` method beacuse each time you click button it's create new object. below can help you :-

1. Make a Window2  class singalton for more detail about singalton click [here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html).

2 .  add null check as below :-

```
    ....
Window2 ww = null; // static or instence variable
......
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
if(ww==null)
{
     ww = new Window2(); 
     ww.someMethod();

}
else
{
   ww.someMethod();

}
```

}
});

Comment: I already tried this with exactly the same if statement but I didn't know what to putin the else sstatement so that it switches to the opened window. It kept opening new windows when I clicked the button though, shouldn't it just do nothing?

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is make two windows and put the actionPeformed method in the main class so that when the button is pressed it displays the second window